# pass json values across pages

Tags: javascript, json

I have defined a json object as

```
  function getPost()
   {
      var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
          var v = {
       "name": {
           "firstname": fname,
           "lastname": lname 
       }
    };
   }
```

How can I make this JSON variable v accessible to other pages. I want to pass the JSON data across pages.

Comment: store it inside a cookie

Comment: `v` is a JavaScript object, not JSON. You can serialize it to JSON though.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data locally within the user's browser using localStorage or SessionStorage([more information](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)) to access your data in all pages.

Take a look at this example:

```
localStorage.setItem('a', '{ "name" : "test"}');
eval("var myObj = " + localStorage.getItem('a'));
myObj.name; // test
```